# Rails with Bootstrap Popover for a destroy action (make me DRY)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a partial `_table_row` this partial holds my html for the output of `@admin_products.all`

In this partial I have a soft delete button which initiates a twitter bootstrap popover, this popover has the hard delete button for the record from the database.

To get the button into the popover currently I've included the HTML content in the partial `_table_row` this as you can imagine repeats the HTML by the number of records in my database.

What I'm trying to achieve is to keep the HTML for the popover in `index.html.erb` and to dynamically add the destroy button into the popover with the correct ID.  This is where I'm having difficulty.

I've tried to use

```
$('.deleteButton').popover({
    html: true,
    content: $('#popoverDestroy').html() + <%= link_to 'Delete', admin_product, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger destroyButton', remote: true %>,
    placement: 'left'
});
```

But as you can understand it will fail as it doesn't know what admin_product is, how would you associate it correctly?

Comment: Where did you put `$('.deleteButton').popover({...})`? In your `assets/javascripts`?

Comment: @AbM yes that's right in the `assets/javascripts` dir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the HTML that you want as a data attribute on the soft delete button, then pull it out again in javascript:

In the partial:

```
<button class='deleteButton' data-delete-button='<%= link_to 'Delete', admin_product, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger destroyButton', remote: true %>'></button>
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
$('.deleteButton').each(function() {
  var softButton = $(this);
  softButton.popover({
    html: true,
    content: $('#popoverDestroy').html() + softButton.data('delete-button'),
    placement: 'left'
  });
});
```

Comment: .data('delete-button') is missing the apostrophe, other than that this basically solved my issue.

Thanks

Comment: The whole idea of having a entire link element inside a data attribute makes me cringe...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of breaking best practice and placing your javascript inline you could actually have the "soft" link actually have the correct URL.

You could do this by having your "soft" link actually point to the delete url and having an event listener which cancels out the click and opens the popover.

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteButton', function(){
  var link = $(this);
  var content = $('#popoverDestroy').clone()
    .append(link.clone().removeClass('.deleteButton'))

  link.popover({
    html: true,
    content: content.html()
  });

  return false;
});
```

This is more inline with the idea of progressive enhancement since you take a normal HTML link element and add behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the product id as an html attribute. In you `_table_row.html.erb`:

`<a class='deleteButton' data-productId='<%= admin_product.id %>'>Soft Delete</a>`

And then in your javascript, you can access the clicked button with the `this` reference if you pass a function to `content` [(reference)](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers):

```
    $('.deleteButton').popover({
        html: true,
        content: function(){
          return $('#popoverDestroy').html() + "<a href='/your-url/'" + this.data('productId') + "data-remote='true' data-method='delete'>Destroy</a>"
        },
            placement: 'left'
        });
```

Comment: This is not great since your are hardcoding the url in your scripts. Its better to use the rails routing helpers instead of just passing the id.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however hardcoding the URL isn't what I was after.